# convert textbox to multiline with jquery

Tags: jquery, textbox, multiline

I have a single line textbox.

I want to with jquery convert it to multiline but control how many lines that are added to it. I want to also be able to limit the number of characters on each line.

Any ideas how I can do this with jquery?

EDIT:

Yes what I meant by textbox was `<input type="text">`

EG. `<input type="text" value="" name="txtTextBox1" id="xtTextBox1">`

Comment: The term "textbox" is not specific enough. This seems to be ASP.NET specific. jQuery doesn't understand that. It only understands HTML. Don't you mean HTML `<input type="text">` or maybe `<textarea>` ?

Comment: @BalusC I would interpret it as turning an `input type=text` into a `textarea`. I think that can only be done by destroying the input, and creating a textarea of the same name.

Comment: @Pekka: true, but there's ambiguity in the term and I judged that based on the OP's posthistory. It may happen that he already has a `<textarea>` with a "single line" restriction generated by some sort of MVC framework.

Comment: @BalusC good point - and it's always better to ask for clarification and code, than guess.

Comment: If you are looking to accomplish this yourself take a look at a very rudimentary example I whipped up at - http://jsfiddle.net/2msUj/ If you are looking for a plugin I would recommend taking a look at James Padolsey's work here - http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have following HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="myclasses" style="color: #123123" value="akira"/>
```

then using following snippet:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.changeToTextArea = function(rows, columns) {
        var attrs = {};
        var text = "";

        $.each(this[0].attributes, function(idx, attr) {
            attrs[attr.nodeName] = attr.nodeValue;
            if(attr.nodeName == "value") {
              text = attr.nodeValue;
              }
            attrs["rows"] = rows;
            attrs["cols"] = columns;
        });

        this.replaceWith(function() {
            return $("<textarea/>", attrs).append($(this).contents()).html(text);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

You should call it with

```
$("input").changeToTextArea(7, 25);
```

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.changeToTextArea = function(rows, columns) {
        var attrs = {};
        var text = "";
      
        $.each(this[0].attributes, function(idx, attr) {
            attrs[attr.nodeName] = attr.nodeValue;
            if(attr.nodeName == "value") {
              text = attr.nodeValue;
              }
            attrs["rows"] = rows;
            attrs["cols"] = columns;
        });

        this.replaceWith(function() {
            return $("<textarea/>", attrs).append($(this).contents()).html(text);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);


$("input").changeToTextArea(7, 25);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="xyzxterms" style="color: #123131" value="akira"/>
```